# Service to communicate components only works on one

Tags: angular, typescript

Create a service to notify my components of any changes to 'idCustomer'.
I would like to do some actions when that property changes. These actions must be done in different components. I made a console.log to know if the change is received. But it only shows me the message for one component. I'm new to angular, if there is a more efficient way to communicate the 'idCustomer' it would be welcome. Section and Customer are siblings.

LoginService

```
  idCustomerChanged = new Subject<string>();
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(requestBody: any): Observable<ResponseBody> {
    return this.http.post<ResponseBody>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/Customer/GetCustomerLogin`, requestBody);
  }

  addIdCustomer(idCustomer: string) {
    this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
    this.idCustomerChanged.next(this.idCustomer);
  }
  removeIdCustomer() {
    this.idCustomer = '';
    this.idCustomerChanged.next(this.idCustomer);
  }

  getIdCustomer() {
    return this.idCustomer;
  }
```

LoginComponent (which changes the 'idCustomer')

```
submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.loginService.login(this.form.value).subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          this.loginService.addIdCustomer(response.data[0].idCustomer);
          this.router.navigate(['/products']);         
        } else {
          this.error = 'Invalid Credentials';
        }      
      });
    }
}
```

NavBarComponent (it shows the message)

```
  idCustomer: string = '';
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.idCustomerChanged.subscribe((idCustomer) => {
      this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
      console.log(this.idCustomer + ' from nav-bar');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

CustomerComponent (this not)

```
  idCustomer: string = '';
  submenusCustomer = ['Profile', 'History', 'Account Payables'];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.idCustomerChanged.subscribe((idCustomer) => {
      this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
      console.log(this.idCustomer + ' from customer-page');
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

SectionComponent (this not)

```
  idCustomer: string = '';
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.idCustomerChanged.subscribe((idCustomer) => {
      this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
      console.log(this.idCustomer + ' from seccion-page');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to add other variable return subject as observable:
On top of your login service and after defining your subject :

```
  idCustomerChanged = BehaviorSubject<any>({})<string>();
//new
idCustomerChanged$:Observable = idCustomerChanged.asObservable();
```

////
On your CustomerComponent and other components :

```
 idCustomerChanged$:Observable;//declare your observable;
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.idCustomerChanged$ = this.loginService.idCustomerChanged$
        this.subscription = this.idCustomerChanged.subscribe((idCustomer) => {
          this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
          console.log(this.idCustomer + ' from seccion-page');
        });
      }
```

Comment: When adding the observable, I get this error: Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: should service observable and component observable has the same observable type:

Comment: idCustomerChanged$:Observable<T>;//declare your observable;

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's work for me .. I'm sorry.. without additional  information I couldn't solve your problem.

Comment: private idCustomer$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
newIdCustomer$ = this.idCustomer$.asObservable();  this.subscription = this.loginService.newIdCustomer$.subscribe(.....)   this works

Comment: Well done . You have an error because You have initiate a  value.Good luck!